# How to rename a property in Xamarin Binding Library

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to build an android binding library for LINE SDK (a SNS service popular in Asia area). I added the jar file from the SDK into my project but it fails to compile because the creators of the SDK just happen to use the same name for a class and its property.

This is part of the C# code that the project generated from the jar file

```
public partial class AccessToken : global::Java.Lang.Object {
    // Metadata.xml XPath field reference: path="/api/package[@name='jp.line.android.sdk.model']/class[@name='AccessToken']/field[@name='accessToken']"
    [Register ("accessToken")]
    public string AccessToken {
        get { /* ... */ }
        set { /* ... */ }
    }
//...
}
```

Now simply put, I want to know how I can rename this property "AccessToken". I tried adding some commands in Metadata.xml but it had no effect. Here's a line of what I've written for reference

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='jp.line.android.sdk.model']/class[@name='AccessToken']/field[@name='accessToken']" name="propertyName">AccessTokenString</attr>
```

I'd be grateful if somebody could help me out. I'm totally lost here.

Comment: Do you have a link to the binding project and/or `.jar` so it's easier to see what the property looked like before? (i.e. it's most likely a get/set method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the only issue is that "propertyName" should just be "name":

```
 <attr path="/api/package[@name='jp.line.android.sdk.model']/class[@name='AccessToken']/field[@name='accessToken']" name="name">AccessTokenString</attr>
```

Answer (score 3):

What @SuavePirate suggests will not work completely (at least not now).

If you use `name` it will also rename the `Register` attribute parameter as `[Register ("AccessTokenString")]` instead of `[Register ("accessToken")]`. So as it states [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata/#Renaming_Members) it will be no longer possible for the Xamarin.Android binding class to access that property because it is not bound to an existent Java member.

To properly change the managed name of a wrapped member, it is necessary to set the `managedName` attribute, i.e.:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='jp.line.android.sdk.model']/class[@name='AccessToken']/field[@name='accessToken']" name="managedName">AccessTokenString</attr>
```